# Getting Twitter API PIN-based OAuth working using PHP?

Tags: php, oauth, twitter

Anyone knows anything about Twitter PHP API that supports [PIN-based authorization](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/pin-based-authorization)? I need an infinite access token (one which will not expire) and i'm actually looking at two libraries:

- [adamwynne / twitter-api](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) seems pretty old, no PIN auth. documentation
- [jmathai / twitter-async](https://github.com/jmathai/twitter-async) a more recent one but no documentation about PIN auth.

I cannot get them work: i can call `getAuthorizeUrl()` and get the PIN and the right callback to my `step1.php` page; but then i'm stuck, and i don't know how to use the PIN submitted by the user. It seems that i need to set `oauth_verifier` parameter of `getAccessToken`, but all this stuff is undocumented.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The first link does not match the text. I'm not sure which library you were referring to.

Answer (score 1):

The PIN should be used as the `oauth_verifier` in `getAccessToken`.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will help.
Assuming you get to the point where you get a PIN number displayed:
1. Copy PIN

Next, you should have a php script to validate the PIN:
2. http://yoursite.com/validate.php?pin=2263903 
Do not expect a response in the browser; the results are in files (see next step)

1. get codes from directory
   -rw-r--r-- 1 beddoe beddoe  42 Nov 28 17:18 access_token_secret
   -rw-r--r-- 1 beddoe beddoe  50 Nov 28 17:18 access_token
2. edit your .php
   Add access token codes from above files